# Cannot resize JButton

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am trying to write a program with swing such that there is a JList on the left and five JButtons on the right. So I wrote code for one JButton, but I am unable to resize or move it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!! Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GenericFrame {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public GenericFrame(){
      prepareGUI();
    }

    private void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Generic Frame");
      mainFrame.setSize(800,400);
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      controlPanel.setSize(800,400);

      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showButtons(){
      JButton showButton = new JButton("Show");
      showButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    System.out.println("hello");
                                 }
                               });

      showButton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      showButton.setLocation(0, 200);


      JButton viewButton = new JButton("view");
      viewButton.setLocation(showButton.getX(), showButton.getY() + 100);


      controlPanel.add(showButton);
      controlPanel.add(viewButton);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
      GenericFrame  swingControlDemo = new GenericFrame();
      swingControlDemo.showButtons();
    }

    }
```

For the record, I'm using IntelliJ. I tried this on multiple machines with different operating systems but this error persists. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a program with swing such that there is a JList on the left and five JButtons on the right.

So when using layout managers you will often need to use nested panels. So in your case I would suggest you keep the default BorderLayout of the frame and add the JList to the frame and a panel containing the 5 buttons to the frame. The basic code would be:

```
JList list = new JList(...);
frame.add(new JScrollPane( list ), BorderLayout.CENTER);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(...);
buttonPanel.add( button1 );
frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

So know your next choice is the layout manager to use for the "button panel". Maybe a vertical BoxLayout? Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and example of each layout manager.

Don't attempt to use setSize() or setLocation() on a component. It is the job of the layout manager to set those properties.